# FTP files in iFrame

Tags: html, iframe, ftp

I'm trying to put FTP link in iFrame, but without success.
FTP have pass and username, and always asks for credentials.
I tried many ways to achieve that
Example : (src='ftp://user:pass@myftpip/'),  but i can t open in my website.

I will be thankful if you have some other solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Since [Chrome is completely removing support for FTP](https://www.coywolf.news/productivity/chrome-removing-ftp/), you should find an alternative solution.

Serving your files and lists of files over HTTP would be the simplest. Most webservers will generate index pages for directories of static files automatically.